# Element does not exist when I want to remove it

Tags: python, xml, loops, python-3.7, elementtree

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Famille.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><HF_DOCUMENT>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>12 BIS</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>12 bis</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>3700744900020</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>BALLON GONFLABLE</Libelle>
        <Livre>0</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>4634510541685140</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>AKATA</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>707003</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Hacomo</Libelle>
        <Livre>0</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>9782756076430</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Draw tome 2</Libelle>
        <Livre>0</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ACCESSOIRE</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Figurine</Libelle>
        <Livre>0</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>AKIKO</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Akiko</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>AKILEOS</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Akileos</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>AKUMA</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Akuma</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ALBIN MICHEL</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Albin Michel</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ALIMENTATION</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Alimentation 5.5</Libelle>
        <Livre>0</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>AMALTHEE</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Amalthee</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ANIME MANGA PRESSE</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Anime Manga Presse</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ANKAMA</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Ankama</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ARTEFAC</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Artefac</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ASIAN DISTRICT</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Asian district</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ASSIMIL</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Assimil</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ASUKA</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>ASUKA</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ATOMIC CLUB</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Atomic club</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <CodeFamille>ATRABILE</CodeFamille>
        <Libelle>Atrabile</Libelle>
        <Livre>1</Livre>
    </Data>
    ...
</HF_DOCUMENT>
```

When I run a simple loop to look into a XML file, I can find every children, 203 in total.

In all those children, I want to remove those with `<Livre>0</Livre>` which represent 63 in total.

My problem is that when I run the same loop with a simple condition to remove only those who respect the condition, I can not remove all of them, only 43 are removed.

```xml
<Data>
    <CodeFamille>9782756076430</CodeFamille>
    <Libelle>Draw tome 2</Libelle>
    <Livre>0</Livre>
</Data>
...
<Data>
    <CodeFamille>ALIMENTATION</CodeFamille>
    <Libelle>Alimentation 5.5</Libelle>
    <Livre>0</Livre>
</Data>
```

Those nodes for example while stay.

Here is my code :

```py
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    if child.find('Livre').text != "1":
        root.remove(child)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

Comment: If the XML contains one child only, which is a problematic one, does it work?

Comment: Maybe deleting elements from `root` while iterating over it messes up the iterations - can you try restarting the whole for loop after removing each child, does it work now?

Comment: Or change the `for` statement so it is iterating over a list, I think `for child in list(root):` should work.

Comment: The change with ```for child in list(root):``` resolved my issue ! Thank you @barny !

To respond at your first assumption, I tried but child which I don't need are still there. Which raise another question :

What is the difference between ```root``` and ```list(root)``` ?

Comment: I think `root` is a generator iterating over the live XML which I’m guessing doesn’t like having elements deleted while iterating. Using `list(root)` creates a simple list from the generator.

Comment: There is no need to put [RESOLVED] or [SOLVED] in the title like in the other sites. Here in Stack Overflow, the green checkmark on the accepted answer and the [green box in the questions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWEuJ.png) already indicates that. There is also no need to put tags in the title, see the [section on Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the for loop like this so it iterates over a list and then deleting individual elements doesn’t get confusled.

```
for child in list(root):
    if child.find('Livre').text != "1":
        root.remove(child)
```